# SSMS 2012 intellisense is not working on one of the servers?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, intellisense

I dont know if this question is asked - I found similar question - *How to enable intellisense*, but my case is little different.

We have 2 SQL Servers 2012 - one is in the other room, other is in our Data Center.

When we write a query on our "next door" SQL Server intellisense working perfectly.

When we write a query on out DC SQL Server intellisense is not wokring - in a new window it works from time to time and does not underline wrong table names. In a window with big script does not working at all.

The DC server is newer version. SSMS lacks SP.

What can cause such issue? Any ideas?

Comment: I think I have same problem [here] on SO.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763723/sql-server-management-studio-2012-intellisense-already-refreshed-cache). The difference is that other people have this feature working. Looks like I'm the only affected.